# Applying corner radius to top part of UIView using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I extended `UIView` to add a round() method to apply corner radius to specific corners:

```
extension UIView {
    func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(radius, radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.mask = mask

        return mask
    }
}
```

In one view controller I have the following hierarchy:

- StackView

  - UIView

Constraint are set to both for top, leading, trailing as 0.
My issue is when I run (only) 5.5 inch screen, the UIView is not stretched all the way as it should be when I apply the corner radius to it:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.greenview.round([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: CGFloat(10))
}
```

If I remove this line it works correctly. Am I not calling this method in the right place ?

Here is a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Shot in the dark, could it be because you're not calling the parent implementation of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? Additionally, I think `layoutSubviews` would be a better place for something like this.

Comment: Yep, doing this in layoutSubviews fixed the problem. You can provide this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting it in 'layoutSubviews' after calling the super method. It's more appropriate for bounds-dependent UI changes.